# Not able to retrieve WSDL content from WSP

Tags: url, get, wsdl, ibm-datapower

I have service (Web Service Proxy) running on DataPower. I am able to test the service from SOAPUI. 
Client application / service is trying pull WSDL from URL like `http://host:port/uri?WSDL`

It is mandatory to pull the WSDL from URL to develop their code.

I have upload the WSDL and share the

```
http://host:port/system/dpViewer/ServiceName.wsdl?filename=local:/Path/ServiceName.wsdl
```

Still They were not able to access the URL from their system.

We performed the connectivity to both system. Everything is working fine.

Any help?

Comment: What is the greater than sign ">" in your URL?  If that's something specific to your environment could that be the problem?  URL schemes only allow letters, digits, `+`, `.` and `-`: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-17

Comment: It is typo. I have corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access using

`http://host:port/system/dpViewer/ServiceName.wsdl?filename=local:/Path/ServiceName.wsd`

As it is internal for your reference and It will open your file in Management / Admin IP. (Most of the place there will be different IP for transactions)

`http://host:port/uri?WSDL` is possible in DataPower

Please follow the below step in your Web Service Proxy (WSP)

1. Edit front side handler (HTTP SOURCE HANDLER)
2. Enable 'GET method'
3. Apply changes and Save Config.

By Default , 'Get method' will not be enabled in WSProxy. As it is disabled, All WSDL get requests are rejected by DataPower.

I hope after this , We can access the WSDL using URL.